# Undocumented method of passing element children: as attributes instead of explicit children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have encountered some example JSX code in a book which took me by surprise - it contains an anchor tag in the single (non-closed) form. I have simplified the code:

```
function CustomAnchor(props) {
    return <a {...props}/>;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <CustomAnchor href="http://reactjs.com">A link</CustomAnchor>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

The code works, but I haven't been able to find any documentation that describes this way of describing the anchor tag in JSX. I expected to have to use an opening & closing A tag, enclosing props.children - i.e - something like this:

`return <a {...props}>{props.children}</a>`

The latter form is in fact how it was done a bit earlier in this same book, and no explanation has been given on the new more condensed form. FWIW, the book is "React Up & Running", by Stoyan Stefanov. I'd appreciate some help here before I consider submitting a suggestion to add an explanation to the book.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmeOxW?editors=0010

Comment: In short, within JSX `<AnyTag children={children} />` is equivalent to `<AnyTag>{children}</AnyTag>`

Comment: By the way, `<a {...props}>{props.children}</a>` will pass `children` twice. This doesn't change the result nor will it break something... just a heads-up.

Comment: @Chris: No, your answer did not really answer the question I had in my head, which I probably didn't express properly. :) I already knew it worked - I can see that for myself, without having to dive into the React code. I want to know two things:
a) How did the author _know_ that they could pass the children that way? I've re-read the React JSX documentation, and it simply isn't at all obvious to me that it's a supported way of passing children.
b) Is it considered "idiomatic" JSX? I know you don't seem to think it is - are you a seasoned React developer? :) :)

Comment: @Chris: re my second example passing children twice, yes, I realise that - I was being lazy. The book actually does it properly, and shows how to delete properties from the props object etc.

Comment: @GregS I think my answer does answer what you asked. I know you can see the result, if I generalize a few things it's so that future readers may find it useful. As for (a) - I cannot answer that. I'm not the author :) I'm however pretty sure that he did. I knew before I actually looked it up in the source code. both `href` and `children` are part of the `props` object, so it makes sense that it would work. The reason `children` gets a special treatment (apart from other `props`) is because JSX tries to look like HTML as much as possible. Though (b) - not really. I find it a bad practice.

Comment: @GregS, and yes, I've been working with React on a daily basis for 2 years and I'm in the top 1% of React "answerers" on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thanks again Chris - I'll try to avoid this syntax then, at least for the time being. I'll see what the rest of the React doco says about props, and then consider submitting an issue against the React docs, and will also submit a (gentle) errata for the book to consider adding an explanation.  However, yes, I agree that it does make sense that it should work.

Comment: React issue submitted: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9718

Comment: The React team appear to be refusing to document this method of passing children, and have closed the issue. Thus, I have logged an errata request against the book in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### JSX and `React.createElement()`

If you look at the [**Babel Compiler**](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=function%20CustomAnchor()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%3Ca%20%7B...props%7D%20%2F%3E%3B%0A%7D), you'll see that this JSX:

```
function CustomAnchor() {
  return <a {...props} />;
}
```

compiles into:

```
function CustomAnchor() {
  return React.createElement("a", props);
}
```

The `createElement()` function has the following syntax, as per the [**official documentation**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement):

> **createElement():**
>
> ```
> React.createElement(
>   type,
>   [props],
>   [...children]
> )
> ```

So your observation makes sense! One would think that since the 3rd parameter is omitted then there shouldn't be any `children`.

---

#### Explanation

So what's going on? One would need to take a closer look at the source code to understand what's going on:

In `ReactElement.js` on line 170 in the react library:

```
ReactElement.createElement = function (type, config, children) {
  var propName;

  // Reserved names are extracted
  var props = {};

  ........

  for (propName in config) {
    if (hasOwnProperty.call(config, propName) && !RESERVED_PROPS.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
      props[propName] = config[propName];
    }
  }
}
```

For each value in the `config` object (i.e the *2nd function argument*!), we pass it to `props` with the `propName` key. However, **remember that you deconstructed `props` in your `<a>` element**.

In other words, this:

```
<a {...props} />
```

is equal to:

```
<a href="http://reactjs.com" children="A link" />
```

This means that `props` object gets both an `href` and a `children` property, which is why you get the result you observed.

---

#### Summary

So in summary, this:

```
<Foo children="Bar" />
```

is equal to:

```
<Foo>Bar</Foo>
```

---

**Opinion:**

That being said, I would rather see the author use your suggested syntax and not the way he/she did it. One would expect educational material to be more clear and precise.